# need your guidance about multiple users working on one project in xampp

Tags: xampp

My friends and I are planning to start working on a web application project and we were wondering is it possible for multiple users to work on the same project and update the files in xampp environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should work with any flavour of subversions

- Git
- SVN (Subversion)
- Others

These programs were taking care conflicts, keep file versions, blame changes, centralization (SVN), user management, permission management, etc. Each of them have different features. These are some of the reference.

3rd parties server:

- SVN

  - Check this comparison table http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/
- Git

  - github (public code - FREE) https://github.com/
  - bitbucket (private code - FREE) https://bitbucket.org/

You can have your own server, these are the official manual to install and configure both in Ubuntu

- SVN

  - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion
- Git

  - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html

There is some "no recommended" option: **Dropbox**. Please try the other options before using this one. This is a horrible option, but it is an option.

**NOTE**: I have extended experience with SVN. However, I really want to start working with Git, but unfortunately, I didn't have time for learn about it.